# Submission on Kaggle

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, kaggle

Kaggle requires us to upload the CSV file, but I don't understand how to do it.
I've a complete code which gives me predictions and I need to write those predictions against their ids and make a CSV file out of them (i.e. containing two columns, one of the id and other of their respective predictions). How do I do it?
It'd be great if someone could help me with a bit of sample python code.

First one is the prediction which comes out as a numpy array

array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,
        0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,
        1.,  0.,  1.])

and the second one is z_test which is a dataframe given by

0      LP001015
1      LP001022
2      LP001031
3      LP001035
4      LP001051
5      LP001054
6      LP001055
7      LP001056
8      LP001059
9      LP001067
10     LP001078
11     LP001082
12     LP001083
13     LP001094
14     LP001096
15     LP001099
16     LP001105
17     LP001107
18     LP001108
19     LP001115
20     LP001121
21     LP001124
22     LP001128
23     LP001135
24     LP001149
25     LP001153
26     LP001163
27     LP001169
28     LP001174
29     LP001176

337    LP002856
338    LP002857
339    LP002858
340    LP002860
341    LP002867
342    LP002869
343    LP002870
344    LP002876
345    LP002878
346    LP002879
347    LP002885
348    LP002890
349    LP002891
350    LP002899
351    LP002901
352    LP002907
353    LP002920
354    LP002921
355    LP002932
356    LP002935
357    LP002952
358    LP002954
359    LP002962
360    LP002965
361    LP002969
362    LP002971
363    LP002975
364    LP002980
365    LP002986
366    LP002989

I've to make a csv file out of these two.
Both have shape (367,).

P.S.- I had a Dataframe X_test on which I had to make predictions, so I copied the id column to z_test using .copy() method.

Comment: Just subset your data frame to only include ID's and predictions. Show us your data frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can e.g. create Pandas DataFrame with columns of interest and save it as csv.

```
submission = pandas.DataFrame({
    "LoanId": LoanId["LoanId"],
    "Prediction": predictions.astype(int)
})

submission.to_csv("kaggle.csv", index = False)
```

Comment: I don't know what's wrong but when I do this I get a KeyError: "Loan_ID". I've saved the Loan_ID in another variable named z_test and on checking z_test it shows the series and Name: Loan_ID, Length: 367, dtype: object

I don't understand what's missing.

Comment: What's the type of z_test? I assumed that (as you described in your question) you have a DataFrame called LoanId.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't clarify it correctly, I've updated the question so you may have a look at it. Tell me if you need any more informations.

Comment: Please run list(z_test) to check what are columns names. Then change second line to: "LoanId": z_test["WhateverColumnNameYouHave"].

Comment: hey, what if i have three columns to write into csv file? I used your method and it messed up the column. I mean if i want the columns to be in order a-b-c but it gets printed as a-c-b. How do i solve this?

Comment: submission[columns] where columns is a sequence of reordered column names, will return a copy of subbmission dataframe with the new order

Comment: like this :-  
submissions[ 'a', 'b', 'c' ]?